# Why dateFormatter is not working everytimes?

Tags: php, datetime, yii, formatting, timestamp

Why once time dateformatter is working, but another time is not? Example:

```
class StronaController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Uzytkownik;
        $wynik = $model::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM uzytkownik');
        for($i=0;$i<count($wynik);$i++)
        {
            echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:s", $wynik[$i]->data).'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

outputs correctly date with pattern but

```
$this -> widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $Dane -> search(),
        'filter' => $Dane,
        'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'imie',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'nazwisko',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'filter' => false,
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'kategoria',
                    'filter' => false,
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'data',
                    'value' => 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:s", $Dane->data)',
                ),
            ), 
        )
    );
```

outputs blank where formatted date date should be? Both data (type timestamp) come from this same table.

Comment: Can you try the type of data to raw ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside cgridview:

```
 array(
    'name' => 'data',
    'value' => function($data, $row){
                  echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:s", $data->data)
               },
      ),
```

Comment: It's working! Can you explain how this function works, please? $row is a numer of grid's row but i can't find nothing about this function in doc.

Comment: Yes, this type of function does not exist in the doc. I tried it myself and worked for me so many times. So you can use it too :)

Comment: Thanks very much, but let me understand what it does,if u can. When i delete $row from arguments it's workig too so i don't think $row necessary is. Finally, *annonymus* function with data from provider as argument let me use echo in value field and make it more _flexible_? I'm right?